# Two variable auto height rows to occupy parent height (no JS)

Tags: html, css

I have two div elements inside a Parent div element with class names `.variableHT`, `.remaining`. Here is the html

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="variableHT">1234</div>
   <div class="remaining"></div>
</div>
```

and here is CSS

```
.parent{
  height:300px;
}
.variableHT{
  height:auto;
  background-color:green;
}
.remaining{
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

I am trying to make two DIVs, first one is auto height element, height is not fixed, it will grow as per the content size. Then next DIV should occupy whatever the space is remaining.
Tried adding margin values but did not workout.

Please help me on this. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GyULa/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this one:

```
.parent{
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.variableHT{
    height: auto;
    display: table-row;
    background-color: green;
}
.remaining{
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GyULa/25/) for it

Comment: Really nice! Good browser support as well.

Answer (score 2):

With overflow:hidden on `.parent` and a height specification on `.remaining` it works:

```
.parent{
    height:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.variableHT{
    height:auto;
    background-color:green;
}
.remaining{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First dirty fix...with "overflow:hidden" ;) But interesting question! Is there a more elegant way?

```
.parent{
    height:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.variableHT{
    height:auto;
    background-color:green;
}
.remaining{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It just works because you are hiding the overflow content, what if second DIV has overflow content. Would user be able to see the content at the end?

Comment: No it will cut content beyond the 300px.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `height: 100%` to the `variableHT`:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GyULa/12/)

```
.parent{
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.variableHT{
  height:auto;
  background-color:green;
}
.remaining{
  height: 100%
  background-color:yellow;
}
```